# HMS Site kit not working in some devices with error code 6004

Tags: android, apk, huawei-mobile-services, huawei-developers, appgallery

tested with Honor 9A its showing error code 6(we have encoded the api key).

tested with huawei nova 7i (emui 10.1.0)its showing error code 6004--we have enabled api properly and cleaned cache

same apk working fine with Cloud debigging

same apk working fine with Honor 9X pro ,version 9.1.1

Answer (score 1):

-If the required API is not enabled, enable it. Then wait for about 15 minutes, clear the HMS Core (APK) cache on the test phone, and check whether sign-in can be successful.
-If the API has been enabled, the possible cause is that an exception occurs when the API is enabled, which rarely happens. As a result, Huawei server does not receive the synchronized API enabling request. In this case, you can manually disable the API and then enable it again to trigger message synchronization. Similarity, clear the HMS Core (APK) cache, wait for 15 minutes, and perform the test again.
To clear the HMS Core (APK) cache, go to Settings > Apps > Apps > HMS Core on your test device, and clear the cache.

I tried the latter solution, and site kit worked properly.

Answer (score 0):

You must enable site kit service in your Huawei developer account.

1. Navigate to Project Setting > General information and click your app.
2. Navigate to Manage API and Enable Site kit.

Suggestion:

1. Check whether the current app has been created and has applied for related services.
2. Check whether the application package name is correctly configured in the Manifest file.
3. Clear the Huawei Core(APK) cache and try again.
4. If the fault persists, contact Huawei technical support.

Reference: https://developer.huawei.com/consumer/en/doc/development/HMS-2-References/hmssdk_jointOper_api_reference_errorcode

Answer (score 0):

In case, that anybody is still struggling with error code 6004, I'll try to summarize my experience.

I did the first 3 steps from [LI HO TAN's suggestions](https://stackoverflow.com/a/69100050/5179134) and still received error code 6004. Also waited for far more time than suggested in [this blog post](https://medium.com/huawei-developers/result-code-6004-reported-when-an-hms-core-sdk-api-is-called-8771f305c508). Reinstalling the application on phone helped immediatelly.

Answer (score -1):

Issue is seen in only two devices.

The possible causes are as follows: checkPermission result: 6004

I can see from CPs logs has  API access permission issue , it is getting ErrorCode: 6004.

Please can you clear Cache the HMS core apk and restart your phone to accept Service Agreement popup and install apk again.